# DocX Set BookMark font styles C#

Tags: c#, docx, bookmarks, xceed

I am using xceedsoftware/DocX to generate word documents from templates in C#, Unable to set styles for bookmark text alone. Trying to create extension, please find below code. I can only see option to set font styles for entire paragraph, not a single bookmark. Am I missing something. How do I set font style, background color, strikethrough, etc., for my bookmark text alone?

```
public static void ProcessBookMark(this DocX doc, string BookMarkName, string BookMarkValue, bool? Bold = false)
{
    var Bm = doc.Bookmarks[BookMarkName];
    if (Bm != null)
    {
        Bm.SetText(BookMarkValue);
        Bm.Paragraph.Font("Arial");
        if (Bold==true)
            Bm.Paragraph.Bold();
    }
}
```

Comment: Raised this issue in their GitHub repo, it's still in open status, https://github.com/xceedsoftware/DocX/issues/233